# How Zero Discount factors are calculated in Oracle and Wellstreetprep?

Tags: yield-curve, ftp

I've some inquiries that may be naive related to ZDF.

I have got a look at those two resources for zero discount factors:

- [Oracle - Zero Discount Factors](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e13524/T397337T397341.htm#ftpuprzcpr)
- [Wallstreetprep - Discount Factor](https://www.wallstreetprep.com/knowledge/discount-factor/)

Unfortunately, I'm still confused about ZDF.

Here is what I get:

The second approach (for calculating the ZDF) in wallstreetprep is the same mentioned in oracle.

Yet, I still not sure about some details:

- in wallstreetprep: each discount factor is calculated independent of the previous discount factor
- in Oracle: the PV of interest payments = Monthly Transfer rate * sum(all previous zero copoun factors)

Q1. **any idea why?** is that because one of them considering it continuous and the other is considering it discrete?

Q2. Also, what is meant by **Monthly Pay Transfer Rates** in Oracle? are they the direct rates coming from **TP yield curve**? Why are they called monthly if they are already divivded by 12 in the next column?

Q3. And on which TP yield curve do we get the rates? the one at **maturity date** or **payment date**? Say for example I have a cashflow for a loan that ends on 2030, and the installments are paid monthly, so the yield curve date for current payment which is within 2024 is got from yield curve of Jan 2024?

Q4. And based on that, the period for the first payment is 1 month, and the second is 2 months, etc? or for all cases the period in 1 month? I mean when I refer to the TP yield curve, I'll be looking for period of two months in the second payment or period of 1 month?

Image from [Oracle - Zero Discount Factors](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e13524/T397337T397341.htm#ftpuprzcpr)
[image: zero discount factors - Oracle]
Image from [Wallstreetprep - Discount Factor](https://www.wallstreetprep.com/knowledge/discount-factor/)
[image: zero discount factors wallstreetprep]